# Why is IFS=; different from IFS=";"?

Tags: bash

I noticed that

```
IFS=;
read v1 v2 <<< "hey;hello"
```

stores the entire string "hey;hello" in $v1

while

```
IFS=";"
read v1 v2 <<< "hey;hello"
```

does the expected action, which is storing "hey" in $v1 and "hello" in $v2

why is that? from what I understand, there's no need to put quotes when assigning a string, as long as there's no whitespace involved

Comment: The issue here is that `;` is the command terminator. Imagine if your code was on one line: `IFS=; read v1 v2 <<< "hey;hello"`. This is setting IFS to a null value.

Comment: `IFS=\;` or `IFS=';'`

Comment: fwiw, `awk -F; '{print $2}' <<< "hey;hello"` generates the same syntax error as `awk -F` ... as mentioned, `;` is treated specially by `bash` so must escape or quote it

Comment: BTW, if you don't have the IFS assignment and the `read` as separate commands, the assignment will apply only to the `read` and the value will return to its former state after `read` completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from what I understand, there's no need to put quotes when assigning a string, as long as there's no whitespace involved

The right-hand side of an assignment only has globbing and string-splitting disabled; otherwise, it's syntactically similar to any other context.

Consequently, it's not just whitespace that needs to be quoted -- you still need quotes when your string contains characters that would be parsed as some kind of syntax (other than the two types of expansion that's squelched inside that context) whose effect you want to avoid.

`;` is a command separator; thus, it terminates the current command when unquoted. Thus, you need to quote or escape it here.